# wifi only works when lan is connected

Tags: networking, router, wifi

Hold tight, this is a strange one...

I have a [board](http://pine64.com) with two network adapters, one lan and one wifi, each one properly configured and has its own ip address on the same network.

Whenever they're both connected, they both work fine, but whenever I disconnect the lan cale, the wifi connection drops too.

[googling](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=932926#p932926) about it points the blame on some router setting, so here's my router model: tp link td-w8901n

thanks

Comment: Please read what this site is and isn't for before posting again.

Comment: Couple of questions: what OS is the board running? Are you *sure* each interface is properly configured? Is it possible the when your LAN connection drops/is removed that your default route for the network is being removed, as well?

Comment: the board uses Debian for pine. I could ssh through both ip's so I conclude that wifi does work (also made sure it registered and got an ip address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure exactly what the problem was but reassigning a new range of ip addresses (no longer using boring 192.168.. ..) and rebooting my board without lan connected did the trick